Fortran pointers and allocated arrays, what happens after a "deallocate"?
The following little code compiles and runs w/o error, and gives expected results:
$ cat ptrpractice.F90
program ptrpractice

integer, allocatable, target :: c(:)
integer, pointer :: d(:)

allocate(c(5))
c = [ (i,i=1,5) ]

d => c
print *,d
deallocate(c)
print *,d

end program



$ ./a.out
           1           2           3           4           5
           1           2           3           4           5

I am wondering, though:  The last print *,d is correct, but is it because d still "has control" of the data of the deallocated array c "for real".  Or is it just fortuitous, i.e. the c array data is no longer assigned to any variable and, if this were a much longer program, would probably eventually be overwritten by something else?

Why do you think that a variable which has been deallocated is still a valid target? (There are very many ways a program is not legal Fortran and a compiler doesn't have to detect. Unless there's a reasonable misconception it's arguably very hard to address every single variety.)

See, for example this and this.

The crucial part of the duplicate target is that "Whenever a pointer's target is deallocated except through the pointer, the pointer's association status becomes undefined." That deallocation is what is done here, and the print *,d is an invalid reference to that pointer with undefined association status.

Admittedly, this is a much better question than the duplicate; realistically, there's probably little to add in an answer.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer
